# iReport - Limit number of records allowed in a sub report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am trying to create a report that will be used for check printing. Its layout is stub, stub, and then check. I thought the best way to do this would be have the detail for the stubs be a sub-report (inserted twice on the report) and the normal detail of the report for the check info. A 3rd party device will handle the "check" base on the info I pass in on the report in that detail band (printing account info for the micr part of the check, adding a signature and some anti theft "stuff").

The problem is I can't figure out how to limit the number of records on the sub-report. I have tried setting the height in the master for the band, in the master for the sub-report property, and on the sub-report for the height of the report. Nothing seemed to work. I also tried to do something like.

```
($V{REPORT_COUNT} %15) == 0
```

Now I am not a Java guy. We use jasper reports for form generation in or python based ERP system.

Any suggestions on how I should go about designing this report? Also to note the "check" part of the report would need to have void details on all pages except one.

## Edit

For example, lets say that we pay vendor FOO for 35 invoices. The layout is going to be stub, stub, check (each a 1/3rd the size of the page). Stub 1 and stub 2 are identical copies of each other. So page one would show 15 invoices in stub one and then show the the SAME 15 invoices in the next stub, and then it would print the physical check details on the bottom 3rd of the page. Page 2 would show the next 15 invoices (same layout as above) but the check details are VOIDED. The last page will show the remaining 5 invoices.

The pages are perforated. We keep 1 stub, and then send the check stub to the vendor.

### jrxml of master report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ap_checks" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3fb75d91-5293-4c89-8450-938a5ac37235">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/Users/pkraus/iReport/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select

appay.id, appay.batch_id, appay.date, appay.payment_type_id, appay.vendor_id,appay.total,
appay.check_number,
vendors.code as vendor_code,vendors.name as vendor_name,
locations.name,locations.address_one,locations.address_two,locations.city,
states.code as state_code,locations.zip_code

from
ap_payments as appay,
ap_payment_types,
vendors,
locations,
states


where
appay.payment_type_id = ap_payment_types.id and
ap_payment_types.print_check = 't' and
vendors.id = appay.vendor_id and
locations.id = vendors.remit_to_id and
states.id = locations.state_id]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="batch_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="date" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="payment_type_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="vendor_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="total" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="check_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="vendor_code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="vendor_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="address_one" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="address_two" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="city" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="state_code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="zip_code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="200" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="true" runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement uuid="71baa8ec-c623-4032-a2b0-381776857ee6" x="0" y="0" width="572" height="152"/>
                <subreportParameter name="check_id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ap_checks_stub.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="178"/>
        <band height="163">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="00182356-2626-4e23-90bf-c8ab35d9bd11" x="380" y="54" width="56" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="042dac2b-6fb5-401d-ab90-11c60cecfa98" x="17" y="114" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address_one}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ec25e5af-5b4d-4f5a-8197-62a84e0b5773" x="17" y="125" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address_two}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="37d3f097-e308-4601-9e1e-e21be81ad57a" x="17" y="134" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="9df87896-ea75-4411-aeb6-db0b1484d219" x="178" y="134" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{zip_code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d99d514e-893b-4b45-ae2b-b8677cee6ed9" x="98" y="134" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{state_code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="926d835e-adc4-4f4b-a29f-5fa18d45090c" x="17" y="74" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vendor_code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="6a8349b5-c86a-4ffc-87b7-84000ebef6af" x="17" y="105" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vendor_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ed874ea2-a95d-47cd-bf8e-b2b559a5dbbf" x="472" y="54" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{check_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

### jrxml of sub report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ap_checks_stub" language="groovy" pageWidth="572" pageHeight="100" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="31589b1a-6d6a-40ff-870b-e84e52104956">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="check_id" class="java.lang.Number"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select
pi.id as payment_id, pi.payment,
vi.number,vi.date,
ap_payments.check_number, vendors.code
from
payment_invoices as pi,
vendor_invoices as vi,
ap_payments,
vendors


where
vi.id = pi.invoice_id and
ap_payments.id = pi.check_id and
ap_payments.vendor_id = vendors.id and
pi.check_id = 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="payment_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="payment" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="date" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="check_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="424923c4-ac9f-4763-919e-afe81870fb6f" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[number]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="4b06f8cf-15d3-44a3-9edf-31e5f760fac6" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="278dc135-0e6b-4d47-84bc-b3bf79c90edf" x="0" y="20" width="100" height="1">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} <= 15]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="80635d70-845f-4893-9f42-f13a064a255d" x="298" y="8" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="bc3035b9-7989-46a4-abf6-ff10ec486a60" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="24">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="3d6e71b0-7fb7-40ec-9e04-529f39003e71" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 $V{REPORT_COUNT} == 15+(($V{PAGE_NUMBER}-1)*15)
```

in the Print When Expression of the break in the subreport detail band.

Comment: If that is the code for your subreport, you might want to try removing the break in the detail band and let iReport generate a detail band once per row.

Comment: Thats how i orginally had it. When i do this i can control the heigh of the report and thus the rows simply by setting the height. However when the report is called as a sub report then the detail just prints for the entire height of the page on the master report which is what i don't want. Basically i need to: print 15 lines of invoice detail, reprint the same 15 lines of invoice detail, print the check details on a per page basis. Also thanks for your help so far!!!

Comment: In the XML for your subreport, it looks like the Print When Expression is being applied to the break. It's inside of the break tags. Can you try removing that from the break and applying it to the subreport's detail band as a whole? Then it should appear after the detail band's band tag but before any of the elements within the detail band.

Comment: Now it limits the out put to the records specified but then doesn't continue past that. So if the check was paying 30 invoices the stub only prints the first 15 and not any more where it should be 15 per page.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I see. Tell us a little more about what the printed output look like if there are more than 15 records in stub1. Does the detail flow into stub2? What if there are more than 30 records?

Comment: This has been very helpful. I replaced x in your code with *, i am assuming you were saying to multiply based on the context of the expression. I now get and error in the print when expression box. -- Encountered:AND

Comment: Replace the and with && (see my changes above)

Comment: Thanks again Lisa! Although the code is only producing a single record I completely get what you are doing and can hack on this now that i get the syntax some.

Comment: Ok, I fixed my answer again. I think your break is key. Once you get things working for the check watermark, let me know what you decide and we can edit the answer again.